# Using ContentResolver v.s. ContentProviderClient in SyncAdapter

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I currently use the ContentProviderClient provided in onPerformSync() for my SyncAdapter. Sometimes I have to make large queries, some of which throw TransactionTooLarge exceptions. (Note: My SyncService runs in a separate process from the application.)

If I were to use a ContentResolver instead - accessed by getContext().getContentResolver() - does the same potential exist to throw TransactionTooLarge exceptions? The query methods for the ContentResolver don't seem to throw RemoteExceptions (via the documentation), and provide much greater flexibility. Could this be a potential solution to my problem?

This is hard to test, as the TransactionTooLarge exceptions are rare and hard to recreate (I see most of them from Crashlytics logs).

I want to avoid wasting my time rewriting everything to use a ContentResolver if it doesn't fix my problem.

TL;DR: Is there any benefit to using ContentResolver over ContentProvider client in a SyncAdapter?

**EDIT:** Here are some of the calls that throw the exception:

**Delete:**

```
String selection = UploadQueueTable.COLUMN_TASK_TYPE + " = 1";
int result = provider.delete(UploadQueueContract.UPLOAD_DELETE_URI, selection, null);
```

**Query 1:**

```
String projection[] = new String[]{UploadQueueTable.COLUMN_URI, UploadQueueTable.COLUMN_ID};
String sort = UploadQueueTable.COLUMN_URI + " LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0";
cursor = provider.query(UploadQueueContract.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, sort);
```

**Query 2:**

```
projection = new String[]{UploadQueueTable.COLUMN_URI};
selection = UploadQueueTable.COLUMN_URI + " = ? AND " + UploadQueueTable.COLUMN_STATUS + " != ?";
selectionArgs = new String[]{uri, "C"};
sort = UploadQueueTable.COLUMN_URI + " LIMIT 1";

Cursor cursor = provider.query(UploadQueueContract.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        null);
```

**Query 3:**

```
Cursor cursor = provider.query(
        UploadQueueContract.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{"count(*) AS count"},
        "(status='E' or status='Q') and task_type = 0",
        null,
        null);
```

Just to name a few...

Interesting side note - this happens almost exclusively to Android OS version <= 5.1, especially LG phones.

**Stack Track** for provider.delete() - (Obtained from Crashlytics, which may not give the whole trace)

```
Non-fatal Exception: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:511)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:542)
   at android.content.ContentProviderClient.delete(ContentProviderClient.java:260)
   at com.forever.forever.Utils.sync.SyncAdapter.databaseCleanupTask(SyncAdapter.java:239)
   at com.forever.forever.Utils.sync.SyncAdapter.onPerformSync(SyncAdapter.java:191)
   at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259)
```

Comment: if you see [CR#delete](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContentResolver.java#1362) and [CPC#delete](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContentProviderClient.java#275) you will notice that in both cases `IContentProvider#delete` is used so i dont think that using `CR` would help, BTW its starange that `delete` method throws that exception, what is the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes... very strange. I also find it really weird that Query #3 also throws the exception, as I'm only trying to get the row count!

Also strange occurrence - it happens much, much more often on LG phones - especially with Android versions <= 5.1

Comment: do you have the stack traces when it happens?

Comment: @pskink - Just added it to the post. Crashlytics doesn't seem to give any more information than that :-/.

Comment: i have no bloody idea whats wrong in ContentProviderNative.java: method `delete` seems to be just directly writing your input `selection` and null `selectionArgs` to the `Parcel`, how can it throw `TransactionTooLargeException` ? magic (black)